# Ubuntu desktop refuses to boot after shutdown via ssh

Tags: ubuntu, shutdown

I'm running ubuntu 21.04 on a workstation PC with a Gigabyte TRX40 AORUS PRO WIFI motherboard. I was using it as a regular desktop PC without issues, but now I'm working remotely on a laptop, and accessing the workstation for compute-heavy tasks via SSH.

Twice now, I've shut down the workstation via SSH (using `sudo shutdown`), and it refuses to boot via the power button afterwards (the box is totally unresponsive, no fans or lights). The first time, I took it back to the assembler, and they performed a CMOS reset, which resolved the issue. I shut it down via SSH afterwards, and it refuses to boot again. I'm attempting another CMOS reset, but I'm looking to root-cause this issue so it doesn't happen again.

Comment: was the grub screen(boot screen) shown?

Comment: No. There aren't any lights/fans at all when pushing the power button. Second CMOS reset didn't help